# xamlを開く時の引数指定について

Tags: wpf, xaml

例えばmain.xamlの中に以下のようなコードがあります｡

```html
xmlns:settings ="clr-namespace:MyApp.MySettings"

<StackPanel  Name="MyPanel" >
    <settings:OtherPage/>
</StackPanel>
```

StackPanelの中身は別のxaml(ここではOtherPage.xaml)を開くようにしてます｡

ここでOtherPage.xamlはコンストラクタでOtherPage(int hoge)をもっています｡

```html
public MySettings(int a)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Console.Writeline(a.toString());
}
```

これを呼びたいのですが､
上記のxamlでコンストラクタの引数をどのように指定すればいいのかわかりません｡

どなたかご教授よろしくお願いします｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML 2009の言語仕様としては[`x:Arguments`ディレクティブ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ee795382(v=vs.110).aspx)が存在しますが、WPFではサポートされていませんので引数のあるコンストラクターは使用できません。

プロパティをうまく使用するか、引数別に派生クラスを定義するなどの工夫が必要かと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます｡　そのような仕様なんですね…